# How to add new int value to an existing one in a sql database through textboxes?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a `TextBox` where I would ask the user to input a score which then gets stored in a database table column (Team1) on button click. Then, the button will also take you to a new page with a new `TextBox` where a new score can be entered also on button click, however, I want the new score to be added to the previous score in the same column (Team1).

code behind button 1

```
private void Btn_TeamSPage2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new TeamS2());

    SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-S2J1U9SJ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Unit4_IT;Integrated Security=True");

    conne.Open();

    string insertQuery = "insert into T_Score(Team1) " +
        "values(@Team1)";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conne);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team1", Txt_Score.Text);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conne.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you query the database to get the existing value of the field and the use an update instead of an insert if the select comes back with a a row of data?

You could also write a stored proc in your db that you could call from the C# code to add the vale to the DB's column